# How do I change the folder icons in the "Places" menu?

Tags: gnome, menu, icons, appearance, folder

How do I change to icons in here?

[image]

Comment: You seem to have ample hard-drive space!

Comment: 2TB is peanuts in the modern world... ;)

Comment: I live in modern world and I only have 500GB, which I share with Ubuntu, elementary OS and Windows.

Thankfully, the modern world also comes with video streaming, so for the last few years I've been using no more than 50GB on my Linux.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to add emblems (like the document, picture frames) on top of the default folder icon, see [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5203/what-happens-if-i-delete-the-default-folders-in-my-home-folder/5204#5204)

If you want to change the underlying icon itself, then there are 2 options

#### Option #1 - Change the icon theme

1. you can change the icon theme by opening Appearance Properties (`System -> Preferences -> Appearance`)
2. In the `Theme` tab click on "Customize..."
3. In the `Customize Theme` dialog, select the "Icons" tab and choose the preferred theme.

#### Option #2 - Customize icon for a specific folder

1. Go to places menu and open the folder you want to customize
2. Press `Alt + Up`  or click `Go -> Open Parent` to display the parent directory.
3. Right click on the directory and select "Properties..."
4. On the Properties dialog, click on the icon on the top left and choose the bitmap in the "Select Custom Icon" dialog that opens.

The icons from various themes installed in your PC are typically stored inside `/usr/share/icons`

Comment: The option #2 works in nautilus, but not in the 'Places' menu!

Comment: I think it should be because the icons are cached by the panel  /UI. Did you try logging out and back in after step 4 ?

Answer (score 1):

Even you can have an image of your own choice if you have a .svg file with you. Just open the folder and then right click in the folder. Choose properties over there. And then click on the folder icon. After which you can browse for a .svg file from your Ubuntu machine. You can download .svg files for free it's so easy. Just google for it. Even some softwares available in the Ubuntu Software Center can create a .svg file. (Inkspace).