# How can i use autorun.ico icon for drives shown in ubuntu

Tags: icons

when I  connect  my usb drives  under ubuntu 16.4 LTS all is  shown  with same  icons so  all look the same. 
I have icon files on my drives  autorun.ico  and in windows i can see them but not in ubuntu. 
much faster  select  drive  when i can see the different  icons.

s

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I assign custom icons to folders?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/79110/how-can-i-assign-custom-icons-to-folders) `autorun.ico` is not supported on Ubuntu, you need .png files.

Answer (score 0):

Copy icon to the USB drive root and Create autorun.inf inside your USB drive root.

inside autorun.inf:

```
[autorun] icon=\icon.ico
```

Eject and Mount it again.

This is how it looks like:

[image: Ubuntu USB Drive Icon]