# How to change folder icons on pcmanfm panel

Tags: lubuntu, icons, pcmanfm

I'm using PCManFM on Lubuntu 14.04:

[image]

As you can see, some personal folders on the **Places** panel have different icons. For example, **Downloads** or **Videos** folder.

[image]

Using `ctrl+d` we can add another folders to the **Places**. A kind of bookmark. For example, my **Dropbox** folder.

So I'd like to know how to change the icon for those folders also.

ps: [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/29862/87678) does not work (at least not on Lubuntu)