# What does Rhythmbox do the first time it is run?

Tags: rhythmbox

Background: I have never used Rhythmbox on this computer.

I just accidentally opened Rhythmbox while my MP3 player was plugged in. Without asking me or explaining what it was doing it started "Importing..." with high disk IO activity in my home folder. I exited the program to stop it, but not before it reached about 30% completion.

What did it just do?

I cannot find any documentation of this behavior on the [Rhythmbox website](http://www.rhythmbox.org) or the [Ubuntu Community Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Rhythmbox).

---

Update: It occurred to me that the IO activity I saw on my home folder might just be coincidental, if Rhythmbox defaults to scanning my home folder when it is first run. I found this in its Preferences screen:

[image]

Does this help explain what Rhythmbox was doing? If it's relevant, [I do not have Music folder in my home folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5203/what-happens-if-i-delete-the-default-folders-in-my-home-folder).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think that Rhythmbox copies music files from MP3-players if the user hasn't told it to do so.

What you saw was Rhythmbox scanning your Music folder. It is default behaviour of Rhythmbox to watch that directory and make sure all music files in that directory are in its music library. It doesn't move or remove or import any music files, it just adds files in your Music folder to the library, so you can play the songs through Rhythmbox.

Answer (score 1):

It copies the music off of your MP3 player into your music directory in your Home folder.