# I deleted a built-in folder in my home folder. How do I get it back?

Tags: home-directory, folder, delete

I delete the Downloads folder from my home folder. When I create a new folder there called "Downloads", it doesn't have the proper icon, and it doesn't show up in the places sidebar.

I tried adding Downloads to `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` (specifically, adding the line `XDG_DOWNLOADS_DIR="$HOME/Downloads/"`), but this didn't do anything it seems.

How can I get my regular Downloads folder back?

Comment: Related (note: no answer here as far as I can tell): http://askubuntu.com/questions/5203/what-happens-if-i-delete-the-default-folders-in-my-home-folder

Comment: Try `XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"`, nor `XDG_DOWNLOADS...`. The folder should get recreated on logout/login.

Comment: @mikewhatever This did it. It seems to have take effect immediately. I don't know why it's the only one that's not plural. Please make your comment an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Done! Glad I could help.

Comment: This is probably the straightforward answer you've been looking for: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/606950/19643

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The entry in `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` should be XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads", not `XDG_DOWNLOADS...`. The folder should get recreated on logout/login.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the answers of this question: [Change the default Downloads directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60161/change-the-default-downloads-directory/60179#60179) of which I reproduce here my own answer in the hope that you wish to check this and inform if it did the trick for you. I am not sure if this will work as I have never done what you did but it's worth to try.

> **Ubuntu Tweak** can be useful for you this time, but includes the install of the [**Ubuntu Tweak**](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/) software, whose intuitive GUI
>   will guide you on this and some other useful processes.
>
> When installed, simply choose Ubuntu Tweak from within the System
>   Tools sub-menu in the main menu. After which you can go to the
>   "Personal" section in the sidebar and look inside "Default folders",
>   where you can choose which will be your default folder for Downloads,
>   Documents, Desktop, etc.
>
> [image]
>
> I hope this help you.
>
> Good luck!

Comment: Note that AFAIK Ubuntu Tweak is not stable just yet for 11.10. For 11.04 and below, though, it's just fine.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice this question was about 11.10. It would also be useful to mention it somewhere in the question or tags. Thank you!

Comment: I don't know whether this question is 11.10-specific. I just wanted to point that out to anybody who *is* running 11.10, which might include the asker.