# Lubuntu: "The specified directory is not valid"

Tags: lubuntu

A little while ago, I removed a few of the default folders from my home directory on my Lubuntu machine.  Now, whenever I log in, I get a warning message that says "The specified directory is not valid".  The really weird thing is that even after I re-created those folders, the message persists.

What is causing this, and how do I fix it?

Info edit:
My `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` showed something like this:

```
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
# 
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/"
```

I commented out the lines that ended with a trailing slash, ran `xdg-user-dirs-update`, and rebooted.  The directories were recreated and message went away, but I would like to know how I can get rid of both the message and the directories at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using Lubuntu 13.10. I removed three of the "default" subfolders in my home folder without any *apparent* ill-effect but see [What happens if I delete the default folders in my home folder?](https://askubuntu.com/q/5203/25656).

- I deleted the following folders:

  - `/home/vasa1/Music`
  - `/home/vasa1/Templates`
  - `/home/vasa1/Videos`
- I edited `~/.config/users-dir.dir` to comment out lines referring to the three subfolders
- I edited `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.conf` to change the line with `Enabled=True` to `Enabled=False`
- I edited  `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults` to reflect the changes made to `~/.config/users-dir.dir`

These changes persist after a reboot.