# For what I have "Public", "Templates" and "Examples" in my home directory?

Tags: directory, home-directory

What is the purpose of  "Public", "Templates" and "Examples" directories in my home directory? What should I put in there? And is ok if I delete them? If yes, then when I create them again they will have the same icons?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/q/5203/25656 and http://askubuntu.com/a/374899/25656

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Searching on this forum fetched me the purpose of the following:

- [public folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174863/what-purpose-does-the-public-folder-serve): The folder is used for sharing files publicly, so your files won't be exposed.
- [templates folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94734/what-is-the-templates-folder-in-the-home-directory-for): To provide a basic skeleton for frequently used contents.

The "examples" folder is acutally a soft link(a shortcut, in Windows terms) pointing to the `/usr/share/example-content/` folder, probably to provide you files to test your video and audio cards and if you have the necessary applications and drivers to run audio and video files.

Its ok if you delete the "public" and "templates" folder and recreate them manually as you create any other folder, but remember to create in your `/home/$USER/` directory; they will have the same icons. However, the "examples" file will have to be created using the terminal(open a terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and typing `ln -s /usr/share/example-content/ Examaples`. This command creates a soft link to the `/usr/share/example-content/` folder(the original folder).

Comment: Thanks for answer me. I deleted "Examples" directory, and when I create a new one It doesn't look like the old one, but when I restore it from trash, yes.

Comment: My bad, edited the answer to reflect what "Examples" actually is.